# What's the equivalent of "long... numbers" params in Clojure?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to call this java method from Clojure and it's throwing me "ClassCastException Cannot cast java.lang.Long to [J  java.lang.Class.cast (Class.java:3003)"

```
public String encrypt(long... numbers) {
  return encode(numbers, alphabet_, salt_, minHashLength_);
}
```

What's the equivalent of calling that method from Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java varargs are syntactic sugar that compiles down to a single array argument. In order to pass data from Clojure into this method, convert your collection of longs to an array with the [`long-array`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/long-array) function.

```
(.encrypt obj (long-array [1 2 3]))
```